# deploying WCF to the WAS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, was

Please allow me to preface that I am in an odd environment.

i need to deploy a WCF service to iis that does not have manager installed, previously i have installed into a virtual directory, etc. that path.  Without manager present this appears to not be an option, so I am wanting to install to the WAS, can anyone please provide any information on this I cannot find anything precise details in regard to this.  do I need it to be in a precise location? are there command lines to execute for this?
I think I handle it via the config files I am using and I am following this example:[How to: Host a WCF Service in WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

but it lacks specific details as to where I need to locate the service files.

installed features include:
.net 3.5.1
Windows process activation service with process model, .net environment,a dn configuration api's
wcf activation with both http activation and non-http activation.
thx.

Comment: Why don't you just install the Admin Manager? Probably be much easier for configuration / maintenance etc. How will you setup App Pools etc?

Comment: I apologize for not explaining more fully, I am trying to get an sql server set up so I can execute an SSis Package using the call from code, which appears to only be able to execute properly if that actual call is on the same machine as the package.  this was initially very confusing as I thought if I had the ssis services installed on the iis machine I would be able to call from my web application.  However I have come to understand I need to use a service on the same machine.  I cannot tell you why the manager stuff is not installed, this environment is very odd.  If I can make case maybe.

Comment: I cannot tell you why it is not installed because there does not appear to be a real answer.  I would really prefer it was on there too.

Comment: and please feel free to tell me I am going the wrong way with direction to the proper way of doing it, I am trying to avoid using dtexec, and agent job, I just want to hit a button in my web app and have the package execute.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this set of instructions for getting this going, everything else just made too many assumptions where this one provided a clear detailed instruction set for actually getting the service going in the WAS.
[Extend Your WCF Services Beyond HTTP With WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx)